# Reledpar, unable to remove line numbering

Tags: pdftex, reledpar

i have this code, i used \Xnonumber and \Xendnonumber but line numbering is still there. Where am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[sameparallelpagenumber,prevpgnotnumbered,shiftedpstarts]{reledpar}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\Xnonumber
\Xendnonumber
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

I am not very experienced with LateX,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Xnonumber` and `\Xendnonumber` concerns line number in the critical foot/endnotes, not in margin.

Use `\numberlinefalse` to disable line numbers in margin.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! In the manual that command was so hidden in a footnote and i didn't see it :|

Comment: Your welcome. When you use reledpar, you must also look on reledmac handbook. And in reledmac handbook, it is not in a footnote.